# add jquery datetimepicker to jqxgrid column of jqwidgets

Tags: datetimepicker, jqxgrid, jqxwidgets

I want to add jquery datetimepicker to a column of jqxgrid. I tried to add by:

```
initeditor: function (row, cellvalue, editor) {
            editor.datetimepicker();
}
```

But this is not working.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this fuction in the column:

```
createeditor: function (row, cellvalue, editor) {
     editor.datetimepicker();
}
```

This fuction is called when you initialize the column.

Comment: I am getting error 'uncaught exception: Missing instance data for this datepicker' when select a date from datetimepicker